# jQuery with tables and mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, html-table

I have a question about jQuery with tables and mouse event.

My app is making with spring MVC (tiles), with jsp

I have to show 2 tables, the second table inside of the first table, when I have to work with the second table, I want to make it affect to the first table and it doesn´t affect to the second table.

I have the next code:
Tiles layout

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="t1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="250"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
        <td width="350"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

jsp page that it change the body

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('table').tablesorter({ sortList:[[0,0],[1,0]] });
            $("tbody tr").mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#CCC");
            });
            $("tbody tr").mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#6E6E6E");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="t2 "class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><spring:message code="box.mac" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.model" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.maker" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.serialNumber" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.vendor" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.purchase" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.warranty" text="default text" /></th>
                <th><spring:message code="box.manufacturer" text="default text" /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1234:5678</td>
                <td>model1</td>
                <td>maker1</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td>vendor1</td>
                <td>26/11/2013</td>
                <td>26/11/2015</td>
                <td>manufacturer1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8765:4321</td>
                <td>model2</td>
                <td>maker2</td>
                <td>9876543210</td>
                <td>vendor2</td>
                <td>01/01/2013</td>
                <td>01/01/2015</td>
                <td>manufacturer2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>0000:1111</td>
                <td>model3</td>
                <td>maker3</td>
                <td>1234567890</td>
                <td>vendor3</td>
                <td>01/01/2010</td>
                <td>01/01/2012</td>
                <td>manufacturer3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The changes are mouse event --> mouseenter and mouseleave with rows

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but if you want the jQuery to only affect a specific table, use specific identifiers in your selectors, i.e. `$("#t2")` and `$("#t2 tbody tr")`

Comment: Thank you for you answer
I have already made it, but it works neither. I have made this: 
`$("#t2 tbody tr").mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#CCC");
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()` function from jQuery ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/children/)) to match only the first (outer) table.

This function works like CSS `>` selector, i.e selects only direct children of an element, not all of the descendants.

Look at [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ7mS/):

- inner table `<tr>` elements have green background defined by CSS
- outer table `<tr>` have red background defined by jQuery; this uses `children()`, so it affects only the outer table `<tr>` elements
- commented out code does not use `children()`, so it affects **all** `<tr>` elements that are descendants of `#outer-table`

In your scenario, you'll probably want to use `children()` to select outer `<tr>` elements and give them the events you need.

I hope my example was clear enough.